# Calling a javascript function on element load

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am working with a ckEditor implementation in my project, and I want to provide autocomplete functionality for one of its dialog boxes. I implement the autocomplete functionality by calling a javascript function on a specific input field. However, I am not completely sure on how to obtain the specific input element, as it only appears after I hit a button in ckeditor, so it is no obtainable on document load.

Is there anyway to fire a javascript function upon the loading of a specific div/element? I am trying to use Jquery's `$().load` function, but it does not seem to be firing. Here is a short example

```
$(".cke_reset_all cke_1 cke_editor_documentBody_dialog").on("load",function(){
console.log("Successful firing")

//some code here
});
```

I am not seeing any text in my console, but div with that class name is appearing.

Everytime the dialog box containing the input loads , the following div is created

```
<div class="cke_reset_all cke_1 cke_editor_documentBody_dialog " lang="en" aria-labelledby="cke_dialog_title_113" role="dialog" dir="ltr">
```

so I am trying to run my autoComplete script after the loading on this div is done, as the input field I want is nested within it. Any ideas?

Comment: That is not what .load does.

Comment: You could use setTimeout wrapping the function you want to fire. Then check within the function if the element exists before executing any other code. Not ideal, but might do what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load` event only applies to some elements, like body, iframe, img, input, script.

In your case, to detect if the input element is present in the page you'll probably have to rely on polling with a setTimeout or setInterval loop. Within the loop, the code will look like:

```
var inputs=$("div.cke_editor_documentBody_dialog input");
if (inputs.length==1) // do something
```

Note that the way you wrote the selector in your question is incorrect.

Comment: Are the performance implications severe if I am polling twice a second?Or pretty negligable. It is a pretty basic webpage, just basic text fields and ckeditor, and I clear the Interval as soon as my function is executed.

Comment: A 500 ms interval should not be a problem, especially as your loop is just a selector. Using setTimeout in a loop would be safer than setInterval to prevent loops from piling up. I often use this with 200 ms or even 99 ms intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The `load` method in jQuery is an AJAX shorthand method, so it's not what you're after here.

If you want to bind to the load event, you need to use the `on` method (or bind in earlier versions of jQuery).

Details here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Ah, I was looking at [http://api.jquery.com/load-event/](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and did not seem to see that it was deprecated. I have edited my question above, to show what I have it changed to, the handler is still not firing however

Answer (score 0):

Bind the On method to the parent div, then look for the id/class and carry out your logic/call a function.

```
 $(function () {

    $('#parentDiv').on('click' ,'yourselectorhere',  function() {

          console.log('working');

        });

   });
```